# how to solve laravel file uploading problem

Tags: php, laravel

I tried to upload image on my public folder but i constantl getting error like this

```
The "C:\xampp\tmp\phpCE7B.tmp" file does not exist or is not readable.
```

Her is my code that i tried so far

```
public function create(Register $request)
    {
        //Registering Students
        $student=new Student;
        $student->name = $request->input('name');
        $student->username = $request->input('username');
        $student->email = $request->input('email');
        $student->password = bcrypt($request->input('password'));
        $student->gender = $request->input('gender');
        $student->phone = $request->input('phone');
        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $file=$request->File('image');
            $ext=$student->username. "." .$file->clientExtension();
            $path = public_path(). '/images/';
            $file->move($path,$ext);
            $student->image = $ext;
        }
        $student->save();
}
```

it saved my info with image in database but after storing gives me the error.Please help me to solve this

***"UPDATE"***

I dont Know what is happening to me, but now its working autometically

Comment: Your code seems ok, this sounds like a server config problem. Make sure you don't run out of HD space, server has access to C:\Xampp\tmp, also check if the phpCE7B.tmp exists there. Also try using $request->storeAs(...).

Comment: i dont have the HD space problem and yes there is no phpCE7B file is exists. And whow to use storeAs image to save it in pubic folder i dont kno can ou tell me how

Comment: just replace ->move with ->storeAs. If that doesn't help, try reinstalling Xampp or move to some other tool that works.

Comment: also check the folder permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem when i'm trying to upload image to public path.
I solved the problem by defining a file system disk in config (filesystems) like that:

```
'YourDiskName' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root'   => public_path(),
],
```

then you can upload images to this path by using StoreAs method:

```
$file = $file->storeAs(YourPathInPublic, YourFileName, [
    'disk' => 'YourDiskName'
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue when I use `public_path()`

Try something like this rather than using `public_path`. Actually there is nothing wrong with your code. But this happens most of the time due to permission levels. As others said you can try reinstalling  Xampp or just try this.

```
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
    $file = $request->File('image');
    $ext = $student->username.".".$file->clientExtension();

    $ext->save('your_public_path/'.$ext);

    //$path = public_path().'/images/';
    //$file->move($path,$ext);
    $student->image = $ext;
}
```

*Example code from one of my project for your info*

```
$image = $request->file('uploadUserAvatar');
$fileName = time().'.'.request()->uploadUserAvatar->getClientOriginalExtension() ;
$image_resize = Image::make($image->getRealPath());
$image_resize->resize(300,300);
$image_resize->save(('assets/img/user_avatars/'.$fileName));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get Form Image
             $image = $request->file('image');
            $slug = str_slug($request->name);
            if (isset($image))
            {
                $currentDate = Carbon::now()->toDateString();
                $imagename = $slug.'-'.$currentDate.'-'. uniqid() .'.'. $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                if (!file_exists('storage/uploads/post'))
                {
                    mkdir('storage/uploads/post',0777,true);
                }
                $image->move('storage/uploads/post',$imagename);
            }else{
                $imagename = "default.png";
            }
//getting coding


 public function index(){

    return view('admin.post.index',compact('posts'));
    }
// show code

<div class="body">
  <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="{{ asset('storage/uploads/post/'.$post->image) }}" >
    </div>
```